# Explain why $\dfrac{1}{(1-x-y+xy)}$ is approximatey $1+x+y$ for small $x$ and $y$.

Tags: calculus

The best I could do to attempt to prove this was to evaluate the limit of the given expression as $x$ and $y$ approach zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac1{1-x-y+xy}
&=& \dfrac1{(1-x)(1-y)} \\
&=& \left(\dfrac1{1-x}\right) \left(\dfrac1{1-y}\right) \\
&=& (1+x+x^2+x^3+O(x^4)) (1+y+y^2+y^3+O(y^4)) \\
&\approx& (1+x)(1+y) \\
&=& 1+x+y+xy \\
&\approx& 1+x+y
\end{array}$$

Provided that $0<x,y\ll1$.

Comment: @

Kenny Lau: I had the same idea , but you deserve it very very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Idea:
$$\frac{1}{1 - (x + y - xy)} = 1 + (x + y - xy) + (x + y - xy)^2 + \dots$$
and then use the fact that $x$ and $y$ are "small" to say that the terms of higher degree are order.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that for $|X|<1$ we have $$\frac{1}{1-X}=1+X+X^2+X^3+\cdots$$
Also, if $x$ and $y$ are both small, then $xy$ will be very small, i.e. negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The product

$$(1+x+y)(1-x-y+xy)$$ equals

$$1+yx^2-y^2-xy+xy^2-x^2,$$

which differs from $1$ by quadratic and higher powers, which are yet smaller than $x$ and $y$ (second order).

Answer (score 0):

MacLaurin expansion of a two variables function gives

$$f(x,y)=f(0,0)+f_x(0,0)x+f_y(0,0)y+O(x^2)+O(y^2)$$

$$f'_x=\frac{1-y}{(x y-x-y+1)^2},\;f'_y=\frac{1-x}{(x y-x-y+1)^2}$$

we have $f(0,0)=f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=1$ therefore

$f(x,y)\approx 1+x+y$

Hope his helps